# Export MultiPolygon data as WKT from QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, well-known-text

I have the polygon data for the city of Kamloops in QGIS 3. When I try to copy features of this polygon and try to paste it over here: https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html I don't get the shape I am looking for, instead I get individual points.

This is how the city of Kamloops looks in QGIS 3:
[image]

This is the MultiPolygon data for the yellow neighbourhood:

```
MultiPolygon (((681749.18023265898227692 5618063.0051740687340498, 681754.9022237341850996 5617959.76259559020400047, 681761.96485726535320282 5617457.0847306102514267, 681766.21101626288145781 5617154.867369020357728, 681772.3200448602437973 5616994.11699739098548889, 681773.16642988566309214 5616972.21210181340575218, 681796.12488878425210714 5616377.3677448034286499, 681796.54249056801199913 5616366.54904075525701046, 681797.34983687940984964 5616345.62910960614681244, 681841.23012263607233763 5616347.4967506043612957, 682305.78420123085379601 5616367.26918454095721245, 682331.76271432917565107 5616368.40384556911885738, 682378.69300003070384264 5616370.44439754635095596, 682394.82700975053012371 5616371.14593769796192646, 682397.83315138705074787 5616371.27661296539008617, 682416.9733991352841258 5616372.10886051505804062, 682612.6998559944331646 5616380.73561305925250053, 682621.46223192382603884 5616139.3100519347935915, 682622.4013459449633956 5616113.57888041809201241, 682623.06902041286230087 5616095.07298767566680908, 682624.61803803034126759 5616052.13997711986303329, 682624.7108312863856554 5616049.56801667064428329, 682624.86335538234561682 5616045.34100752882659435, 682624.8829871965572238 5616044.7970038503408432, 682624.95663059782236814 5616042.75600204430520535, 682624.9878615690395236 5616041.89056355506181717, 682630.78011429589241743 5616042.09398256614804268, 682670.68674091901630163 5616043.49529568292200565, 682670.90159843489527702 5616037.5292805153876543, 682675.72000393178313971 5615903.55108064785599709, 682676.40518959239125252 5615884.49996326491236687, 682676.71181218326091766 5615875.97349041327834129, 682658.43578196037560701 5615875.32573693431913853, 682646.25576743017882109 5615874.89399767480790615, 682648.83315795566886663 5615803.23710456676781178, 682649.73082346469163895 5615778.27992776781320572, 682650.0787901422008872 5615761.24932891689240932, 682651.64998592715710402 5615760.71000024490058422, 682655.24999797716736794 5615759.33999842591583729, 682658.85001002810895443 5615757.96999660693109035, 682668.49000195413827896 5615754.42001194506883621, 682678.73999386932700872 5615750.96998567134141922, 682686.7800090005621314 5615748.20000415667891502, 682695.11999568343162537 5615744.94999104551970959, 682704.57999182678759098 5615741.53999953530728817, 682714.93999901600182056 5615737.6699938103556633, 682724.92998988274484873 5615733.86000810004770756, 682734.16998761054128408 5615730.39998919889330864, 682742.61998956557363272 5615727.5199924111366272, 682752.71000307984650135 5615723.92001249268651009, 682760.78998871333897114 5615720.63998937420547009, 682769.38001594971865416 5615717.52000891976058483, 682779.82998889964073896 5615713.94001425057649612, 682783.76499488670378923 5615712.48001454025506973, 682787.7000008737668395 5615711.02001482993364334, 682797.57001597248017788 5615707.5699885543435812, 682805.38000793103128672 5615704.55999124236404896, 682809.26000628154724836 5615703.1449904777109623, 682813.14000463206321001 5615701.72998971305787563, 682821.77999499626457691 5615698.45999135076999664, 682833.3399847811087966 5615694.09999353624880314, 682844.47000249102711678 5615690.16999992728233337, 682854.32000020798295736 5615686.54000999964773655, 682865.37001265119761229 5615682.54000375047326088, 682877.86998398415744305 5615677.83999962173402309, 682899.75001045595854521 5615669.90000713802874088, 682910.34000868629664183 5615665.81999562308192253, 682922.36001268494874239 5615661.4699904341250658, 682933.70000405423343182 5615657.21001526527106762, 682944.80001175589859486 5615653.10998636856675148, 682956.24998626857995987 5615649.03000698424875736, 682967.96998658496886492 5615644.60998915508389473, 682978.78001536149531603 5615640.67000292055308819, 682988.869996746070683 5615637.06999086961150169, 683000.10999759752303362 5615632.69000780396163464, 683012.23998473957180977 5615628.5299910232424736, 683021.71000563912093639 5615625.28001004457473755, 683033.91999804601073265 5615620.58000591397285461, 683045.73998888023197651 5615616.17001284100115299, 683055.87999765295535326 5615612.39999763295054436, 683068.28001059964299202 5615607.86000403389334679, 683079.8999882685020566 5615603.50999884493649006, 683090.21999282483011484 5615599.71999838575720787, 683101.17001475114375353 5615595.80999002791941166, 683113.26999188493937254 5615591.23998642340302467, 683121.75999647378921509 5615587.96998806297779083, 683135.07001309096813202 5615583.14001553878188133, 683146.57001499179750681 5615578.89999349229037762, 683157.90001373551785946 5615574.62999356910586357, 683171.1200003307312727 5615569.96999207139015198, 683182.82001539599150419 5615565.56999162398278713, 683196.20001252368092537 5615560.71000909246504307, 683216.16000900603830814 5615553.30001133307814598, 683229.59000139124691486 5615548.52000193670392036, 683247.42998684942722321 5615542.07999573089182377, 683258.6099998177960515 5615538.06999685615301132, 683271.67000801209360361 5615533.459990618750453, 683283.62999199610203505 5615529.26000333577394485, 683296.99999649729579687 5615524.77999762073159218, 683311.59000097680836916 5615519.73998717591166496, 683322.99001236073672771 5615515.90998408384621143, 683334.51999213825911283 5615512.15998625941574574, 683345.34001354034990072 5615508.74999474734067917, 683355.93001177068799734 5615505.64999954402446747, 683366.6200005179271102 5615502.21999065019190311, 683378.15001242607831955 5615498.24999440833926201, 683391.32000376284122467 5615493.91001397557556629, 683401.96998987719416618 5615490.03001562505960464, 683404.17999879270792007 5615489.36001168750226498, 683406.39000770729035139 5615488.69000774808228016, 683429.66000518389046192 5615481.17998733930289745, 683455.50999576691538095 5615472.92000592313706875, 683460.45624903589487076 5615471.32474429905414581, 683462.10500815790146589 5615470.79291009716689587, 683465.59698900207877159 5615374.99998660758137703, 683467.521003189496696 5615322.22600704059004784, 683472.29201600886881351 5615192.02399146370589733, 683474.29198700282722712 5615136.44700009562075138, 683477.60198799706995487 5615044.47500279545783997, 683486.86399520561099052 5614787.95701054856181145, 683486.8502754271030426 5614787.95648842491209507, 683009.15200639050453901 5614769.7640058696269989, 682990.77399355079978704 5614769.05298718251287937, 682888.41356148850172758 5614765.09145736135542393, 682666.18999514821916819 5614756.49100373685359955, 682704.38772214390337467 5613951.3741079568862915, 682704.39099946804344654 5613951.30499497428536415, 682739.68100094329565763 5613100.09600520879030228, 682773.87001428939402103 5612275.44898862950503826, 682802.85299823246896267 5611466.06498468294739723, 682831.83601430524140596 5610656.65299495868384838, 682022.06901326216757298 5610627.23399838246405125, 680876.57099900394678116 5610592.24698873795568943, 680750.00000153295695782 5610588.3929840661585331, 680378.05699844658374786 5610577.06401350162923336, 678960.56601355038583279 5610608.28499213792383671, 678753.33598828967660666 5610612.84201496839523315, 678725.94099641777575016 5611421.70800891704857349, 678699.20098741538822651 5612230.63800707831978798, 678670.56199398543685675 5613039.71799101307988167, 678663.59600938577204943 5613245.17700814083218575, 678643.39699315465986729 5613848.30399866215884686, 678602.80199993867427111 5614663.97201461158692837, 678564.26998588070273399 5615428.42599302530288696, 678543.97300336230546236 5616052.76398606225848198, 678537.91691800858825445 5616239.06517998874187469, 678536.31403339188545942 5616288.37277879007160664, 678535.71501404512673616 5616306.79856987483799458, 678533.50208124332129955 5616374.86981332302093506, 678532.90792165417224169 5616393.14780351333320141, 678531.4128513615578413 5616439.25602707639336586, 678529.70947820320725441 5616491.78902692534029484, 678511.65447457600384951 5617048.61337144859135151, 678510.55912537220865488 5617078.65007936581969261, 678510.55959929898381233 5617078.65010346285998821, 678482.20800631213933229 5617856.09299302287399769, 678476.63701312709599733 5618022.99993051402270794, 680012.58704791776835918 5617277.9119978416711092, 679989.16508059948682785 5618027.55298521183431149, 680399.24061763565987349 5618035.53692436404526234, 680750.00000153295695782 5618042.36600838601589203, 681300.94342885818332434 5618053.09273850731551647, 681620.56199200637638569 5618059.31571034900844097, 681621.00875233579427004 5618059.1275614183396101, 681749.18023265898227692 5618063.0051740687340498)))
```

When I plot this over here:
https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

This is what I get:
[image]

I am not sure what's going on there, is there something wrong with the data?

Comment: Probably wrong crs, try wgs84 (epsg:4326).

Comment: What coordinate system is your polygon data in?

Comment: thanks @MrXsquared , you are correct. I resolved the crs and it worked!

Comment: @hky404 When you changed to wgs84 (epsg:4326) did the MultiPolygon have the same units? I've a similar problem and I converted the layer to wgs84 (epsg:4326) but I still get something similar to yours, nothing like lat lon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your multipolygon WKT with OpenJUMP and it seems to be valid. The problem you faced is that the site https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html assumes that WKT is using WGS84 longitude-latitude coordinates but your WKT is in some other coordinate system. If you want to use just that site for visualizing you data you must first convert your layer into EPSG:4326 with QGIS.